# How to return a value in php member function and get the value in another page

Tags: php

```
class.php

class Database {

function select_user($formation,$department,$table) 
{

if(($formation=="Select All") and ($department=="Select All"))
    {
    $select_user=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ". $table . "  order by dateofjoin DESC");
    echo "SELECT * FROM ". $table ." order by dateofjoin DESC";
    }
    else
    {
    $query="SELECT * FROM". $table ." WHERE formation='$formation' and department='$department' order by dateofjoin DESC";
    //echo "SELECT * FROM ". $table ." WHERE formation='$formation' and department='$department' order by dateofjoin DESC";
    return ($query);
    }

}
```

In viewtudent.php,i am passing arguing for the function like

```
$obj= new Database;
 $obj->select_user($_POST['formation'],$_POST['department'],'user');
```

so please msg me how to get the value from class.php,,thx,,,

Answer (score 0):

```
include("class.php");
$obj= new Database;
$obj->select_user($_POST['formation'],$_POST['department'],'user');
```

Include the `class.php` in order to use the the class from that file.

Comment: when i print,the query is working perfect,,,what i need is,,,how to get the value from that function?

Comment: hope u understood me,,how to get the values and store in a variable

Answer (score 0):

```
you have made some changes there is change in first if statement ...


if(($formation=="Select All") and ($department=="some department name"))
{
$select_user=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ". $table . "  order by dateofjoin DESC");
echo "SELECT * FROM ". $table ." order by dateofjoin DESC";
}
```

Comment: when i print,the query is working perfect,,,what i need is,,,how to get the value from that function?

Comment: hope u understood me,,how to get the values and store in a variable

Answer (score 0):

first of all make space between FROM and table in second string query

```
$query="SELECT * FROM ". $table ." WHERE formation='$formation' and department='$department' order by dateofjoin DESC";
```

Second - make public property, and name it as you wish, for example `$class_var`, then set this property as class and you can get the values from class:

```
class Database {

    public $class_var;

    function select_user($formation,$department,$table) 
    {
           $this->class_var->{any_property_or_method};
     //.....
    }
}

include("class.php");
$class = new Class();
$db= new Database();
$db->class_var = $class;
$db->class_var->{whatever_in_class}
$db->select_user($_POST['formation'],$_POST['department'],'user');
```